# Calling $this->getChildHtml on a new block outside template file

Tags: blocks, holepunching, caching

**I'd like to call `$this->getChildHtml('product_type_data')` to get product's price outside view.phtml template file.**

Currently I have `echo $this->getChildHtml('product_type_data')` and that outputs contents of 'catalog/product/view/type/default.phtml'.

I need to move it to a file in a custom module(cache hole punch) so that it gets called separately. So in this file I've done:

```
$block = Mage::app()->getLayout()->createBlock('customerprices/catalog_product_view', $this->getId());
$block->setTemplate('catalog/product/view/type/default.phtml');
$block->setIsLoggedIn(Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn());
$out = $block->getChildHtml('product_type_data');
```

But in this case $out contains an empty string. 
Do I need to set something on this block so that it will return price html? If so how? I have a current $_product object if that's needed.

I would appreciate any suggestions.

---

**Using Mage::getBlockSingleton(...)**

when I use this code:

```
$thatx = Mage::getBlockSingleton('catalog/product_view');   
$cnamex = get_class($thatx);
echo 'cname: '.$cnamex;
```

$cnamex does not contain class name(empty string/variable). I consequence I can't run any methods on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need only product price block to be rendered you can use like this:

```
$out=Mage::getBlockSingleton('catalog/product_view')->getPriceHtml($_product);
```

See `getPriceHtml()` method of `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Abstract` which is parent class of `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View`

#### Second Way

Extend your block `customerprices/catalog_product_view` from `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Abstract` and use it:

```
class MyCompany_Customerprices_Catalog_Product_View extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Abstract{

}
```

and

```
$block = Mage::app()->getLayout()->createBlock('customerprices/catalog_product_view', $this->getId());
$out=$block->getPriceHtml($_product);
```

Comment: Hi mageUz. Thank you for the reply. I would be really great to use this method to get product object but unfortunately object doesn't load. I run it from module's file(caching injector).

Comment: @Alan see another solution on the answer